# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType' CSV

Tags: python, csv

```py
import csv

class User:
      #creates a user
      all = []
      def __init__(self, name : str, lastname: str,password: str, password2: str, username: str, saldo: int):
         #ssert saldo >= 0, "data is negatif that can't be right hu"
         self.name = name.capitalize()
         self.lastname = lastname.capitalize()
         self.saldo = saldo
         self.password = password
         self.password2 = password2
         self.username = username
         
         
         User.all.append(self)
```

```
      @classmethod
      def instantiate_with_csv(cls):
         with open("banking sytem/user.csv",'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            items =  list(reader)
         for item in items:
            User(
                name= str(item.get("name")),
                lastname=str(item.get("lastname")),
                password=str(item.get("password")),
                password2=str(item.get("password2")),
                username=str(item.get("username")),
                saldo=int(item.get('saldo')),
            )
```

```
User.instantiate_with_csv()
print(User.all)
```

to get the value of a csv file and make a object out of it

Comment: Given that the "saldo" column is the only one that uses `int()`, have you checked your csv to see if the "saldo" column can be empty? What should a blank be turned into?

Comment: `saldo=int(item.get('saldo') or 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
                saldo=int(item.get('saldo')),
```

Blank CSV entries will produce a `None` value, and `int(None)` won't make you happy.

There is an opportunity to default such values, perhaps to zero
if that makes sense in your use case.

```
                saldo=int(item.get('saldo', '0')),
```